# YouTube API. Check for user was subscribed

Tags: api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

What the best way to determine when authorized user was subscribed to YouTube channel by channel's id through YouTube Data API? I assuming it is possible somehow by "Subscriptions.list" API method. But how exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the channelId of the channel you want to check the user is subscribed to, you can perform an HTTP GET request on the [`subscriptions/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) endpoint with the parameters `part` set to `id` and `mine` set to `true`:

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=id&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You could also pass in `snippet` for part to get information about each channel the user is subscribed to.  With this approach, you would have to iterate through every channel that authenticated user is subscribed to, and check if your channel exists in that list.

You could also send an authenticated POST request to the [`subscriptions/insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) endpoint with the `channelId` of the channel you want to subscribe to with the `part` param `snippet`, and if the user is already subscribed to that channel, the request will return a 400 error with the message `subscriptionDuplicate`.

```
HTTP POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thank you for such wide answer! Btw I have done with following approach: part=subscriberSnippet, forChannelId=my_channel_id, mine=true.